# How can I solve the warning DEPMOD

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

```
root@akshit-Vostro-1550:~/Desktop/Device_Drivers/newsource/linux-2.6.32# make install
sh /home/akshit/Desktop/Device_Drivers/newsource/linux-2.6.32/arch/x86/boot/install.sh 2.6.32 arch/x86/boot/bzImage \
        System.map "/boot"
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 2.6.32 /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 2.6.32 /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32
depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_VaDo0c/lib/modules/2.6.32/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 2.6.32 /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 2.6.32 /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 2.6.32 /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-42-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-42-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-41-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-41-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-39-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-39-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-33-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-33-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-32-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-32-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-31-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-31-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-30-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-30-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-25-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-25-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32.old
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda1
done
root@akshit-Vostro-1550:~/Desktop/Device_Drivers/newsource/linux-2.6.32# cd /boot
root@akshit-Vostro-1550:/boot# mkinitramfs -o initrd.img-2.6.32 2.6.32
depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_zuISx2/lib/modules/2.6.32/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
```

After "make modules_install" i am trying to do "make install" but i face warnings module is could not open. So please someone help me to get out this problem.

Comment: I am very thankful to stackoverflow members. you guys are showing so many solutions to my questions.

Comment: Someone help me friends i am waiting for your answers..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where the problem occurs. It's just warning because I am doing work on ARM kit so I am compiling kernel for that kit using cross compiler on my host PC. So there it will create all modules using cross compiler but platform dependency is change so this warning comes. When I go to further process on my work it is going perfectly..

Comment: I found another reason on  this issue when I am trying to "make modules_install" some warning like "depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_VaDo0c/lib/modules/2.6.32/modules.builtin: No such file or directory". But I try to solve this warning by use "sudo apt-get dist upgrade". But Still I get this warning. For that one only I am facing problem. So if anyone knows how to solve this please help me